# How to connect to a Gremlin Websocket in Go?

Tags: go, websocket, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm trying to connect to Gremlin which should be running on port 8182 (`[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182`)

When I'm connecting to: `ws://127.0.0.1:8182` I'm getting the response:

```
2017/11/03 17:20:04 ERROR: database with the name 'gremlin' gave an error when connecting: websocket: bad handshake.
```

The Gremlin server responds with:

```
[WARN] HttpGremlinEndpointHandler - Invalid request - responding with 400 Bad Request and no gremlin script supplied
```

I'm using [Gorilla Websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) in Go to connect:

```
gremlinGrpcAddress := fmt.Sprintf("ws://%s:%d/", f.config.Host, f.config.Port)

var dialer *websocket.Dialer

clientConn, _, err := dialer.Dial(gremlinGrpcAddress, nil)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

f.client = clientConn
```

**UPDATE:**
Connecting to `echo.websocket.org` works, so somehow it is something in the Gremlin server.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the available gremlin client libraries for Go, either to import or as an example of how to write a client?

Comment: Hi @Adrian, yes, I'm looking at https://github.com/go-gremlin/gremlin but because it's not being maintained I'm creating my own web socket connector.

Comment: PS: added an update

Comment: There's also https://github.com/qasaur/gremgo which looks more complete.

Comment: Hmm, same error with Gremgo. It keeps returning a `bad handshake`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the config YAML file.

What is needed is the correct channelizer.

GOOD:

```
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
```

Comment: Jason's comment is relevant for 3.2.2 and above as well https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/x4hiHsmTsHM/Xe4GcPtRCAAJ

Answer (score 1):

Connect to `ws://localhost:8182/gremlin` instead of `ws://localhost:8182`. There are several references to it in the Apache TinkerPop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/) and the go-gremlin [README](https://github.com/go-gremlin/gremlin/blob/master/README.md).